# dashboard change only content without full page reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i have seperate sidebar and content when any menu from sidebar is clicked it should show only proper content without page refreshing it works but in a wrong way like this

my sidebar is that
**side.html**

```
<div class="row2 col-2">
<div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col-12 side-bar p-0">
        <ul class="side-bar-items p-0">
            <li class="side-bar-item">
                <a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}" title="" class="active">
                    <i class="fa fa-font-awesome"></i>
                    Boshqaruv paneli
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="side-bar-item" id="loadbasic">
                <a href="{% url 'contacts' %}" title="" class="navlink">
                    <i class="fa fa-font-awesome"></i>
                    Aloqalar
                </a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      <div>
    </div>
```

my js code

```
$('.row2').on("click", ".navlink", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel click
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.row2').load(page);
});
```

if you notice when contacts is clicked the url did not change. How can i solve this problem?

my **contacts.html** page looks like this

```
 {% include 'dashboard/header.html' %}
{% include 'dashboard/side.html' %}

<!-- Dashboard -->
<div class="row3 container-fluid">
    <!-- Counting row -->
    <div class="row counting-row pb-5">
        <div class="col-10 offset-2 pt-0 pl-5">
            <div class="row justify-content-between start-dash mb-4">
```

thanks beforehand!

Comment: So you ectually want to change route but without reloading?

Comment: If so. You should consider to use React: https://reactjs.org/

Comment: @MrLine thanks for the advice but right now i have no time to learn reactjs

Comment: if you want to change url without reload, use [history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History)

Comment: if you want to change content without reload, fetch data and replace DOM manually (or simply use css `hidden`)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load the content inside the sidebar where the navlinks are available instead of loading on the sidebar content. Pls try to change the DOM id or class where you need to display the content. 
$('.row2').load(page); with 
$(ElementClass).load(page) (ie) Here ElementClass is which you have for Sidebar Content where the page need to load.
You can update the url in the address bar without reloading by

```
$('.row2').on("click", ".navlink", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel click
  var page = $(this).attr('href');
  $(ElementClass).load(page);
  history.pushState({}, null, page);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: thank you very much it works but url did not change. How can i modify it?

Comment: So you seems to change the url in the address bar right? Can you tell me which framework you are using and can you accept and upvote my answer, if my solution worked for you.

Comment: I am not using any framework but only javascript for UI historypushstate did not work very well

Comment: Pls check my edit, I hope it will work for you. history.pushState or history.replaceState in only the option to change url. Pls check the history api documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API